# Job that executes command inside a pod

Tags: bash, kubernetes, jobs

What I'd like to ask is if is it possible to create a Kubernetes Job that runs a bash command within another Pod.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: run-cmd
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 180
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: run-cmd
        image: <IMG>
        command: ["/bin/bash",  "-c"]
        args:
        - <CMD> $POD_NAME
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

I considered using :

- Environment variable to define the pod name
- Using Kubernetes SDK to automate

But if you have better ideas I am open to them, please!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it for backups or what does the command do?

Answer (score 0):

The Job manifest you shared seems the valid idea.

Yet, you need to take into consideration below points:

- As running command inside other pod (pod's some container) requires interacting with Kubernetes API server, you'd need to interact with it using Kubernetes client (e.g. `kubectl`). This, in turn, requires the client to be installed inside the job's container's image.
- job's pod's  service account has to have the permissions to `pods/exec` resource. See [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468369/how-to-control-access-for-pods-exec-only-in-kubernetes-rbac-without-pods-create).